# C# PDF library for headless Linux server

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, mod-mono

I'm currently trying to find a PDF library which will run without a running X server. I have already tried the following...

1. Migradoc/PDFSharp (requires X)
2. ITextSharp (requires X)
3. SharpPDF (might work, but I am looking for something with a bit more features)

The library **does not** have to be opensource or free.

My solution runs on Apache2.2 mod_mono.

Does anyone know of such library?

--- edit ---

The test code used for itextsharp, which produces errors on my testserver is listed below (the code for Migradoc and SharpPDF is just as simple):

```
using System;
using sharp=iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.xml;
using System.IO;

namespace pdftester
{
    public static class ITextSharpTest
    {
        public static void HelloWorld(string filename)
        {
            Stream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            sharp.Document document = new sharp.Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new sharp.Paragraph("Hello world"));
            document.Close();
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: You're request is already answered multiple times! And none of these libraries needs X!

Comment: I've no idea if this will run under Mono, but have a look at http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-8.htm

Comment: Are you sure about iTextSharp? I've used that with an ASP.NET MVC implementation and had no need for UI for the library. There may be dependencies but that's almost certainly for build, just include the libraries and you can still run headless.

Comment: @Andreas Rehm
I've used the search engine and checked the first 150 posts, and none of these answered my question. Those who asked about server side PDF engines were running in IIS, where you do actually have a display. However, if you are sure that it have been answered, please post the link here :)


@Tchami
Thanks, I will have a look at it.


@Lazarus
I have tried all the above mentioned on the server via SSH (using a commandline program i have developed) and it failed with: "System.NotSupportedException: Could not open display (X-Server required. Check you DISPLAY environment variable)"

Comment: The error can't be caused by any of the mentioned libraries. It must be your program. Maybe your implementation has some issues?

Comment: I am not convinced that it's an error in my program. I'm simply doing a "hello world" PDF based on their documentation.

I know for sure that Migradoc/PDFSharp is utilizing GDI+. Mono has implemented libgdi+, but it depends on X11 libraries. This dependency seems to require that an X11 server is running, as it's actually attempting to draw stuff to a display buffer.

I've listed the code used for itextsharp in the original post. Please let me know if you can spot any potential errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has given a definitive answer to the thread, i'm closing it.

I've chosen to go the sharpPDF way, as it's the only one supported on my server. I'll simply have to implement what's needed for my project.

Thanks for the help received so far :)

Comment: More than 7 years later, I'm having the same issue - trying to move some Windows software that uses PDFSharp to Linux and it's demanding an X server. Did sharpPDF let you get around this, or did you find something else?

Comment: 4 years later, PDFSharp still has that dependency on System.Drawing.Common.